# Is there any way to sort this dictionaries by lowest value from keys?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, split

I just wanna sort these dictionaries with some values from an input file.

```
def sortdicts():
    listofs=[]
    listofs=splitndict()
    print sorted(listofs)
```

The `splitndict()` function has this output: 
`[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}, {'a': 7, 'c': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 0}]`

While the input is from another file and it's:

```
a 1
b 2

c 2
d 4

a 7
c 3

x 0
y 5
```

I used this to split the dictionary:

```
def splitndict():
    listofd=[]
    variablesRead=readfromfile()
    splitted=[i.split() for i in variablesRead]
    d={}
    for lines in splitted:
        if lines:
            d[lines[0]]=int(lines[1])
        elif d=={}:
            pass
        else:
            listofd.append(d)
            d={}
        print listofd
    return listofd
```

The output file should look like this:

```
[{'y': 5, 'x': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}, {'a': 7, 'c': 3}
```

This output because :
It needs to be sorted by the lowest value from each dictionary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array = [{'y': 5, 'x': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}, {'a': 7, 'c': 3}]`

for the above array:

`array = sorted(array, lambda element: min(element.values()))`

where "element.values()" returns all values from dictionary and "min" returns the minimum of those values.
"sorted" passes each dictionary (an element) inside the lambda function one by one. and sorts on the basis of the result from the lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [{'y': 5, 'x': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}, {'a': 7, 'c': 3}]
sorted(x, key=lambda i: min(i.values()))
```

Output is

```
[{'y': 5, 'x': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}, {'a': 7, 'c': 3}]
```